# Analysis Services Power Query Editor performance

Tags: sql, azure, ssas, powerquery, azure-analysis-services

Currently I am building a model in Visual Studio for Azure Analysis Services, but I am experiencing very slow performance of the Power Query editor.

I am trying to do a left join on a table of about 1.600.000 rows. The table I am joining with is around 50 million rows. The merge-step works, but when I try to expand the columns it is downloading all the 50M rows for some reason. At least the status bar at the bottom indicates this.

This is quite annoying as it will do this every time I try to edit the query sequence.

- Already tried setting several indexes on the SQL table
- The Azure SQL server does not show usage peaks of 100%, max 80% sometimes

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Is this a tabular model? Are you using DirectQuery (if it's available)? Do the 1.6 million rows have matches in all of the 50 million rows?

Comment: Also, can you connect directly to the Azure SQL table instead of using AS? Is there a reason you would prefer to connect to the AS instance instead of the SQL Server instance?

Comment: This is a tabular model, and not using Direct Query. All 1.6M rows have matches. I am using AS because I need to create a model in there for use in PowerBI

Comment: Could you create the model in PowerBI or SSDT instead? You'll get better performance if you connect to the Azure SQL Server instance and apply the transformations, and then load the results into the PowerBI or SSDT model. Do you need Analysis Services-specific features like row or object level security?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in SSMS that the PowerQuery editor creates so-called folded-queries and also introduces sorting statements which I don't setup in the editor.

So I fixed my performance issues by enabling legacy datasources in the Visual Studio options. With this I can write my own SQL statement which are many times faster.

Does anyone know why this is happening in the PowerQuery editor, and if using this legacy way of working has drawbacks compared to the editor?

@alejandro: I need Analysis Services mainly for the fast cache it provided. I tried to load the tables in PowerBI directly, but this became totally unresponsive.